# GCP AI Notebook %pip install outside of PATH + can't change path

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, path, pip, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I'm trying to use the [GCP's AI Notebooks](https://console.cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/). However, when you `%pip install` a package, it gets installed outside of the system's path you can't call it from the shell. Tried to change the default path but I'm doing something wrong. Would appreciate suggestions.

Here's an example:

```
[1] %pip install kaggle --user
 ... Installing collected packages: kaggle
  WARNING: The script kaggle is installed in '/home/jupyter/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed kaggle-1.5.6
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
#restarted the kernel
[2] import kaggle
 #works
[3] !pip show kaggle
Name: kaggle
Version: 1.5.6
...
Location: /home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
...
[4] !kaggle -v #doesn't work
/bin/sh: 1: kaggle: not found

[5] !echo $PATH
 /usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
[6] !export PATH=$PATH:/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages 
#no output
[7] !echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
# path is unchanged
```

When I try the same `!export` line in the shell, the path changes and the shell finds my executable. When I try it in the notebook, it doesn't.

Comment: What shell do you use? `bash`? I think its config file should be `~/.bash_profile`, not `~/.profile`.

Comment: Using bash but I don't have a ~./bash_profile in my home folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip is telling you exactly what to do here:

> `WARNING: The script kaggle is installed in '/home/jupyter/.local/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

You can use the following to append to environment variables from within Jupyter:

```
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + '/home/jupyter/.local/bin'
```

After which `!kaggle -v` should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, but after this command, the path came out as "$PATH:/home/jupyter/.local/bin" - is there an escape char missing somewhere?

Comment: $PATH and $$PATH produce the same result: "$PATH:/home/jupyter/.local/bin" - the previous folders got deleted.

Comment: Sorry about that, looks like the magic commands won't work here. I've updated my answer to something that I've tested and will work!

Comment: Sweet! Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the path at in the jupyter notebook startup script, so that you don't have to add these lines every time you start a notebook:

Open a Terminal, then do

```
cd ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/
nano startup.py
```

In this file, add

```
import os 
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + '/home/jupyter/.local/bin'
```

Exit and save (ctrl+x) and voila!